# Change transaction isolation level

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that in some cases when inserting values it uses transaction with the default transaction isolation level (read committed). These transaction sometime may go in sleep status and the when happened cause the application not responding + hanging out. How can I change the status or the isolation level of those sleeping transaction when I'm having there ID(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't/can't. The transaction isolation level determines what locks a given operation will take and what locks a given operation will ignore. Changing the transaction isolation level mid-transaction would cause a lot more problems than it would solve.

My advice would be to find out why your process is sleeping so much and resolve that. Alternatively, break your transaction up into smaller pieces.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working on an existing system and I cannot break up the transaction into smaller pieces :( that is why I'm looking for changing the transaction level.